# How to encrypt large strings with pri/pub keys using PHP

Tags: php, encryption, public-key-encryption

I need to encrypt large string is it possible to do it with RSA public key private key ?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how large the string you're wanting to encrypt is - if it's larger than the modulo - it's usually best to just encrypt a randomly generated string of x bytes that serves as the key to a symmetric algorithm and then use that symmetric algorithm to encrypt the "large string".

eg. encrypt a 16 byte (128 bit) key for AES and then encrypt the "large string" not with RSA but with AES and append it to the RSA encrypted AES key.

Or you could use a larger modulo, too, but the larger the modulo the more time it'd take to perform encryption / decryption.